# How to change from email address in smtp php mailer function sendmail()

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using the below code and I got emails but from email address not coming from `setFrom()` function. Can anyone help me to set desire from email address in SMTP `sendmail()` function?

```
include_once 'Mailer.php'; 

$body = 'TEST, Testing of email.';
$subject = 'Email Demo';
$email = 'test1@gmail.com';
$fromEmail = 'test2@gmail.com';    

$objMail = new Mailer();
$objMail->mail->AddReplyTo('test3@gmail.com', 'Test 3');
$objMail->mail->SetFrom('testfrom1@gmail.com', 'Test From 1');
$objMail->mail->AddAddress('test4@gmail.com', 'Test 4');
$objMail->mail->IsHTML(true);

$objMail->sendmail($email, 'Test', $subject, $body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered many times before. Gmail does not let you set arbitrary from addresses, though you can add a limited number of preconfigured aliases in your account.

Comment: Should i do it with hotmail account and hotmail live smtp configuration?

Comment: Try it, but be aware that setting arbitrary from addresses is generally a bad idea and is likely to get your messages rejected by SPF if you're forging anything.